# Install docker specific version on Centos7 machine

Tags: docker, centos, docker-machine

Previously I had installed docker-ce-20.10.6. However, I want to use docker-ce.20.10.5. I have uninstalled docker-ce-20.10.6, clean up /var/lib/docker folder and reinstall with command "yum install docker-ce-20.10.5.
But this isn't installing docker-ce-20.10.5, rather pointing to 20.10.6.

any idea how can I make 20.10.5 version as default, and remove 20.10.6

```
# docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.6
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        370c289
 Built:             Fri Apr  9 22:45:33 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.5
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       363e9a8
  Built:            Tue Mar  2 20:32:17 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.4
  GitCommit:        05f951a3781f4f2c1911b05e61c160e9c30eaa8e
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc93
  GitCommit:        12644e614e25b05da6fd08a38ffa0cfe1903fdec
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0

# docker --version
Docker version 20.10.6, build 370c289
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Centos
For Docker CE Versions

```
sudo curl -SsL https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo -o /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo
```

Now to Install specific Docker versions on Centos/Fedora
For Latest Docker CE versions (≥17.06.0 CE)

```
sudo yum --showduplicates list docker-ce
sudo yum install docker-ce-17.06.0.ce-1.el7.centos
or
sudo yum install docker-ce-17.06.0.ce-1.fc25
```

check for reference
https://medium.com/@gauravsj9/how-to-install-specific-docker-version-on-linux-machine-d0ec2d4095